# Add Notification to Array of Realm Results

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, tableview, realm

Just started using Realm for an iOS project and I've looked at the example and docs, but can't seem to figure out how to get fine grained notifications for an array of Realm results.

For example, if its just a Results object you can do this

```
// Observe Results Notifications
notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
  guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
  switch changes {
  case .initial:
    // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
    tableView.reloadData()
    break
  case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                       with: .automatic)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                       with: .automatic)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), 
                       with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    break
  case .error(let error):
    // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
    fatalError("\(error)")
    break
  }
}
```

and this works just fine for a normal tableview with no sections as it just inserts the new cell into section 0.

However, taking a look at the [GroupedTableView](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/GroupedTableView) (tableview with some sections) example they simply add a notification block to the Realm object itself. Which notifies you of any change, not particular insertions/deletions etc.

Like so:

```
    // Set realm notification block
    notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] note, realm in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

While this works, it really isn't the best solution since you lose the nice animations provided by iOS for free.

My question is really just, how could I add fine grained notifications to an array of Results

`var objectsBySection = [Results<DemoObject>]()`

I've thought about looping through the array and adding a notification block to each result object, however since new Result objects can be added to this 2D array, this doesn't seem like a good solution.

Does anyone have experience using Realm with a sectioned tableview that has dynamically growing amount of sections/cells?

**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ UPDATE WITH ANSWER ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

So thanks to @bogdanf, I was able to find a solution to this. I am posting my solution here since it is not exactly the same as @bogdanf suggested, but his answer led me to the solution so here it is.

First, in my application sections are not exactly infinite. The user when adding objects adds onto them, but they're limited quantities. I.e I can create an array and append my actual Realm objects to them, thus allowing me to group the objects via their appropriate section.

So thats the first step, I create an array of all my sections, in my app this amounted to ~48 sections, so the runtime won't be too bad when adding notifications.

After creating my array of sections, I query realm for the correct object that corresponds to the sections like so:

```
func initObjectsBySection() {
    print("Initializing")
    for (index, section) in sections.enumerated() {
        let unsorted = realm.objects(Object.self).filter("section == %@" , section)
        let sorted = unsorted.sorted(byProperty: "year", ascending: false)
        objectsBySection.append(sorted)
        registerNotification(for: objectsBySection[index], in: index)
    }
}
```

And `registerNotifcation` is what bogdanf suggested, with some changes:

```
func registerNotification(for objects: Results<Object>, in section: Int) {
    let token = objects.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            break
        case .update:
            // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init(integer: section), with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            break
        case .error(let error):
            // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
            fatalError("\(error)")
            break
        }

    }
    notifTokens.append(token)
}
```

The reason I am just simply reloading sections instead of deleting or inserting specific rows, is because this does the same thing, it's more concise and a crucial factor is it allows for the section title/height to be recalculated.

Since I am starting with an array of sections ~48, this would mean that if the user were to start from a new install, their would be 48 empty sections and that looks horrible.

Instead, what I do is just set the header for the section to 0, i.e:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsBySection.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsBySection[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return objectsBySection[section].count > 0 ? 44 : 0
}
```

And that's basically it.

Comment: How do you know which objects go in each section (in other words, how *objectsBySection* is created) ? If the criteria could be expressed as a Realm query the solution is really simple.

Comment: @bogdanf In the example I linked (from Realm) they figure out which objects go for which sections using a query, [look here.](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/GroupedTableView/TableViewController.swift#L56-L60)
So it is a Realm query.

Comment: did you try add objects to few sections at once? i think it would crash your app, because of few tableView updates runs on main thread in the same time

Comment: This seems very... hackish

Comment: @SAHM it was but it worked for my application. Sadly realm doesn’t support 2D arrays like CoreData does. However I’ve since moved to using delegation instead of Realm notifications for this same application.

Comment: What do you mean by delegation?

Comment: @SAHM instead of relying on realm notifications I use a delegation protocol between my view controllers to determine when tableviews need to be updated and such

Comment: I wonder if this is a case in which Core Data would have been the better solution. Only because I have similar code and it seems like handling it with Core Data (specifically NSFetchedResultsController) doesn't involve so much... work.

Comment: @SAHM for sure Apple has better API’s for their own platform and would have probably made this easier but Realm isn’t too bad for a free open source DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go like this, looping through the array as you suggested:

```
var objectsBySection = [Results<DemoObject>]()

// Fill the objectsBySection array like in your example
...


for (index, objects) in objectsBySection.enumerated() {
    registerNotifications(for: objects, in: index)
}
```

where the `registerNotifications(for:in:)` method is defined like this:

```
func registerNotifications(for results: Results<DemoObject>, in section:Int) {

    let notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }

        switch changes {
        ...
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }), with: .automatic)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section)}), with: .automatic)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }), with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            break
        ...
        }
    }
    notificationTokens.append(notificationToken)
}
```

We assume `var notificationTokens` is defined at the class level.

Now, you mentioned that new sections could be added at any time, so let's deal with that too. So we add the plain old non-fine grained notification block and we check if there are new sections added.

```
notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] note, realm in
    // Let's see what the section list looks like now
    let sections = Set(realm.objects(DemoObject.self).value(forKey: "sectionTitle") as! [String])

    if !Set(sectionTitles).isSuperset(of: sections) {
        sectionTitles = Array(sections)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So, in my simplistic approach, it reloads everything only if new sections are added. If you want to benefit from the nice insert animations you could check instead what sections were added, insert them one by one in the table and then add the new objects to them.

Note: My method to check if sections were added is quite intensive, basically it iterates through all the objects in the DB, so you may want to check it with a realistic load in your app. Unfortunately, until Realm would permit `distinct` or `group by` queries this is the only way I could imagine to solve this issue.

Comment: I have an extension in the actual app im working on to remove same objects, and make them unique. Thanks for the awesome write up, when i get home will give this a shot and update the answer!

Comment: So this solution didn't exactly work for me, but I am marking you as the answer since this awesome answer led me to figure out a solution. Updated my question with the solution I used.

Comment: I think @distinctUnionOfObjects works with realm, but I don't know how to use it in Swift. how would you change your answer Bogdan about sections ? https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: And when several sections will try to update at the same time you will receive "invalid update" error.